# Contour integral $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2\sin(1/z)}{z-2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

How do I compute this integral?

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2\sin(1/z)}{z-2} \, dz$$

I tried substituting $1/z$ with $z$ and ended up with

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(1-2z)} \, dz$$

At this point I thought of using the residue theorem and got $2i\pi(2-4\sin(\frac{1}{2}))$ but the correct answer should be $\frac{i\pi}{6}$. Can someone help me?

Comment: How you subbed 1/z? What do you mean by that? After the sub will the curve remain the same?

Comment: @IrbidMath : $$ \begin{align} & w = 1/z \\ {} \\ & dz = -dw/w^2 \\ {} \\ & \frac{z^2\sin(1/z)}{z-2} \,dz = \frac{(1/w^2)\sin w} {1/w-2} \cdot\frac{-dw}{w^2} = \frac{\sin w} w \cdot \frac 1 {2w^2(w -\frac 12)} \, dw \end{align} $$ As $z$ moves counterclockwisearound the unit circle, $w$ moves clockwise around the same circle. That multiplies the integral by $-1.$ The function ​$w\mapsto\dfrac{\sin w} w$ may be treated as an entire function.

Comment: @Edgar your final answer looks correct.

Comment: @Edgar I got the same answer as you too.

Comment: One can check the result numerically... pari/gp delivers for `intnum(t=0, 2*Pi, exp(2*I*t) * sin(exp(-I*t)) / ( exp(I*t) - 2 ) * I*exp(I*t) )` the result `2.1588488780269327642348413996048524801 E-58 + 0.51709261418082126109706704849010303464*I` which matches the value for `? 2*Pi*(2 - 4*sin(1/2))` numerically, this last value being
`0.51709261418082126109706704849622901620`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting $\pi i/6$? I am also getting a residue of

$$2-4\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

We can see this directly using power series centered at zero:

$$\frac{z^2\sin(1/z)}{z-2}=$$

$$z^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1!z}-\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\cdots\right) \cdot\left(\frac{-1/2}{1-z/2}\right)=$$

$$z^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1!z}-\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\cdots\right)\cdot \frac{-1}{2}\left(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2^2}+\cdots\right)$$

We can now see term by term that the coefficient of $1/z$ will be:

$$\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{3!2^0z}+\frac{1}{5!2^2z}-\frac{1}{7!2^4z}+\cdots\right)$$

Which is clearly:

$$2-4\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The coefficient of $1/z$ cannot depend on $z$.

Comment: I was just writing out the multiplied terms. You factor out the 1/z part. Sorry, I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Well this problem was in a test and my teacher said the answer was $\frac{i\pi}{6}$, I thought I was doing something wrong